# Command to reinstall ubuntu mate desktop

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-mate, session

When I booted up my machine, it said `failed to start` session. So I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd>, then I login. Now I need to install the mate desktop. But I don't know what the command for that is, I know what the command for unity is but not for mate. I have very limited file space and using unity would eat it all up, so I need e command to install the mate desktop.

Comment: apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop --reinstall

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yeah your right, sorry about that :/

Comment: No worries , we mark duplicates to save effort and improve the one best answer.